# Unable to use jquery jquery.autocomplete.js in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying  to  make  autocomplete  on   input Text search field  with  help  of jquery.autocomplete.js in  angularjs. But  it is  not working.I checked  firebug console  there is  no error.Please  help me.

code

```
 app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        elem.autocompleteArray({
            source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), 
            minLength: 2
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
    return {
        getSource: function() {

        return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
       }
     }
 }]);
```

Html code

```
 <input type="text" auto-complete/>
```

Comment: Are you sure your service is injected correctly into your directive?

Comment: check via chrome or firebug debugger if the injected "autoCompleteDataService" has the functions you defined in your service. or use a console.log(autoCompleteDataService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have couple of syntax mistakes, some missing braces, naming and lastly, you forgot to surround the element with JQuery, in any case here's a working example using JQuery ui autocomplete .

**Example:**

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
    return {
        getSource: function() {

        return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
       }
     }
 }]);

 app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        $(elem).autocomplete({
            source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), 
            minLength: 2
        });
    }
    }})
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/gKcMP/

**Update:**

Working example with JQuery [autocomplete](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete_docs.txt)  plugin (only works with jquery version <1.9)

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
    return {
        getSource: function() {

        return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
       }
     }
 }]);

 app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        $(elem).autocompleteArray(autoCompleteDataService.getSource(),{
             minLength: 2
        });
    }
    }})
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/gKcMP/2/

Comment: @Alex.its not working for me..i  tried to  console.log(autoCompleteDataService) in firebug console it gives  me Reference Error:  autoCompleteDataService is not defined.Can you tell me  how to correct this?

Comment: as I said you have some missing braces in your directive, have you tried looking at my live example?

Comment: yes..you are  using  jquery-ui.js and  i am  using  jquery.autocomplete.js . so  elem.autocompleteArray is  correct  synatx as  per [this](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete_docs.txt)..

Comment: MinLength did not work..and i tried minChars this also  did not work

Comment: this is a plugin problem and not angular.